# JPA unique attribute not rendered

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple `pojo` with an `email` attribute which should be unique in database table:

```
@Entity
public class Customers implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer cID;
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String email;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String username;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String password;

//getters/setters/constructors
...
}
```

And this is `jsf` form bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class RegistrationBean implements Serializable {

private String username;
private String password;
private String email;

//getters/setters

public String registeration() {
    Customers newCustomer = new Customers(email, username, password);
    CustomerService customerService = new CustomerService();
    if (customerService.persistCustomer(newCustomer) == true) {
        return "Succ?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    return "fail?faces-redirect=true";
   }
}
```

And this is my `form`:

[image]

(Button action is to `registeration()`)

But i try two times with equal `email`s, and it stores successfully!

[image]

Why it doesn't display any error about identical `email`?

Comment: Ensure about this uniqueness of email addresses in the said column on the web layer itself before a nasty exception with a long exception stack-trace is thrown from the upper service layer. You can in this way, show a user-friendly error message to the end-user(s) associated quite easily.

Comment: @Tiny How can i show `hibernate` error messages in `jsf` customized?

Comment: You need to ensure uniqueness of email addresses in this case. This is a kind of validation - it is termed "*validation*". The service layer should not be responsible for performing this kind of validations. It is the full responsibility of the client application (JSF or whatever you may be interested in). Do not let JPA/Hibernate do this kind of things - do not leave it to JPA/Hibernate. Instead do it too early (JSF) before the control passes to JPA/Hibernate. In case of JSF, you can do this using a custom validator the usual way (yes, you need an addition query but it is unavoidable anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Column(unique = true)` causes JPA-Implementations to create an unique constraint on the database-column when auto-creating the table.
If you add this Annotation parameter after the tables were created, it has no effect. You probably want to add the unique constraint to the column manually or let your JPA-Implementation recreate the table.

Comment: yes, it works. How can i display `Hibernate/JPA` errors in jsf correctly?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I don't know much about JSF.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"EMAIL"}))
public class Customers implements Serializable {
...
```

Comment: That annotation has nothing to do with validation.